# When I test an app integrated with the HMS Health Kit on my Huawei Mate 30 Pro, why cannot I obtain the number of steps?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

What should I do if the error code `50005` is returned when querying the step count using the corresponding method under `DataController`? (The scopes of Health Kit I applied for from the Huawei Developers website have been approved.)

> 2020-05-26 11:41:21.195 17338-17338/com.hauwei.hmsdemo I/DataManager: 
>   read failure 50005:**Unknown authorization** error
>
> 2020-05-26 11:41:21.203 17338-17338/com.hauwei.hmsdemo I/DataManager:

---

The following lines are used for querying the step count:

```
public void readSteps(View view) throws ParseException {

    DataCollector dataCollector = new DataCollector.Builder().setPackageName(context)
        .setDataType(DataType.DT_CONTINUOUS_STEPS_DELTA)
        .setDataStreamName("STEPS_DELTA")
        .setDataGenerateType(DataCollector.DATA_TYPE_RAW)
        .build();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    Date startDate = dateFormat.parse(BEGIN_TIME);
    Date endDate = dateFormat.parse(END_TIME);

    ReadOptions readOptions = new ReadOptions.Builder().read(dataCollector)
        .setTimeRange(startDate.getTime(), endDate.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();

    dataController.read(readOptions).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ReadReply>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ReadReply readReply) {
           ……
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
           ……
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the lines you used for querying the step count. The issue lies within authorization granting. It should be noted that the data that an app can access must be within the scopes granted to the app on the Huawei Developers website and within the range of data for which the user approval has been granted on the device side.

Regarding this issue, verify that the read/write permissions for the step count data have been granted when the app is displaying the data authorization screen.
You can refer to the following code, or refer to the sample code for Health Kit at 
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Examples/healthkit_Android_sample_code.

```
private void dataAuthorization() {
    Log.i(TAG, "begin sign in");
    // The data that can be used here and its read/write permissions can only be those you have applied for from the Huawei Developers website.
    List < Scope > scopeList = new ArrayList < > ();
    scopeList.add(new Scope(Scopes.HEALTHKIT_STEP_BOTH));

    HuaweiIdAuthParamsHelper authParamsHelper =
        new HuaweiIdAuthParamsHelper(HuaweiIdAuthParams.DEFAULT_AUTH_REQUEST_PARAM);
    HuaweiIdAuthParams authParams =
        authParamsHelper.setIdToken().setAccessToken().setScopeList(scopeList).createParams();

    final HuaweiIdAuthService authService =
        HuaweiIdAuthManager.getService(this.getApplicationContext(), authParams);

    Task < AuthHuaweiId > authHuaweiIdTask = authService.silentSignIn();

    authHuaweiIdTask.addOnSuccessListener(huaweiId - > {
        ......
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
            ......
        }
    });
}
```